# Printing multiple columns with awk but joined by semicolon

Tags: awk

I am using awk to filter output returned by a previous command (docker image ls) which is tab separated columns.

I would like to print the first 2 columns with a : in between.

What I've tried:

`docker image ls | awk '{ print $1\:$2}'`

But no matter how I tried to print $1 and $2 I still get

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    { print $1 >>>  \ <<< \ $2}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

How can I use : in the output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings should be inside double quotes:

```
docker image ls | awk '{print $1 ":" $2}'
```

Comment: difficult choice for accepting, both answers work but this seems more useful as a general formatting direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Set the `OFS` variable to the desired separator:

```
docker image ls | awk -v OFS=":" '{print $1, $2}'
```